# How do I output coloured text from by unit tests in the R# Unit Test Session window in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, nunit, resharper

How do I output coloured text from by unit tests in the ReSharper Unit Test Session window in Visual Studio. I am using Resharper VS addin which I think produces the Unit Test Window.

I am using this with nunit and wish to use c# Console.Write to generate coloured text to this window.

Comment: not sure if this is resharper specific or just something nunit allows for.

Comment: In your menu: `ReSharper` -> `Windows` -> `Test Session Window`. So at least the window you are talking about belongs to ReSharper.

Comment: I think that window is an embedded IE window, but that Resharper preprocesses the test output before throwing it in there. That preprocessing does give you limited abilities, like creating a link to a local file with "file://c:/path/to/file". That has proven me quite useful in debugging xml request/response sequences, which I write to disk and then link up in the test output.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to unit test the `ConsoleColor` of your output?

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible in my opinion. You write text to this window by using `Debug.WriteLine()` or `Console.WriteLine()`.
How do you want to pass information about the color? I gave it two tries:

- `HTML` is not parsed
- The `richtext` format is not parsed

I have no other idea and I don't think that it is working somehow.

Comment: Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkMagenta;

Comment: tascanius, You're right. It is simply not supported. But there is R# feature request, you can vote on: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-255660

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible because the output of log4net ColoredConsoleAppender is black and white in Resharper test runner.